# modal.style.display does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a feedback form on a modal box that get changed to a message 'Thank you for your feedback!' once the user submits it, thanks to the following code:

```
const modal = $(".feedback-modal")
modal.html("<div class='modal-content col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2'><span class='close'>&times;</span><p>Thank you for your feedback!</p></div>");
modal.style.display = 'none'
console.log('OK')
```

The first two lines works perfectly. However, the third one does not. I want the modal box to disappear, hence I set de `.style.display` to `'none'`, but it does not work, although if I write that line in the browser console, it works. Notice that the `console.log('OK')` does not get executed either.

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `modal` is a jQuery object, therefore `.style` is `undefined` and this causes the script to crash.

Instead just use the jQuery `.hide()` method.

```
const modal = $(".feedback-modal")
modal.html("<div class='modal-content col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2'><span class='close'>&times;</span><p>Thank you for your feedback!</p></div>");
modal.hide();
console.log('OK')
```

Comment: Yes that was the problem; thank you ! + I added a SetTimeout function to make it look good (disappear after 2sec).

Comment: @JulesCorb I'm glad it worked, I was going to mention you will probably need a timeout or it will automatically disappear before seeing the new HTML :)